# I want to add bokeh effect to uiimage added in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, image

i am creating an app where i want to add bokeh effect to image added and i searched a lot about how to implement this in iphone app but i can't find any code for reference but i have seen may apps on app store which give that effect to images but i didn't found any tutorial for iPhone. so any one here can help me out from this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you can do is follow this tutorial [Create a Bokeh image](http://inspiredology.com/how-to-create-a-simple-bokeh-effect/) , its essentially meant for photoshop but you can achieve the same effects in iOS programmatically. For example :-

- You can create your brush
- You can manually set the RGB
- You can draw some Bokeh circles
- Add a blur effect

You can tweak these things up a bit and make your Bokeh image . Anything else please let me know !!